# Why my Pyinstaller exe fails on other computers on the line that starts a Java program?

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have implemented a interface with some code that I want to use as an executable.
I used PyInstaller to create my .exe from my .py

My .exe is well running on my computer.

But when I try to run it from an other computer I get this result :

```
E:\global_nice_interface>global_nice_interface.exe
E:\global_nice_interface\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "global_nice_interface.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "Preprocessing\launch_server.py", line 18, in start_NLP_server
  File "subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
[11376] Failed to execute script global_nice_interface
```

The corresponding line in my code is :

```
subprocess.Popen('java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port'+StanfordCoreNLP_port+' -tiemout 15000',cwd=StanfordCoreNLP_path)
```

the variables StanfordCoreNLP_path and _port are defined as this :

```
StanfordCoreNLP_path = os.path.abspath('stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05')
StanfordCoreNLP_port = '9000'
```

I check the StanfordCoreNLP_path by printing it (2nd line of the "result") : it is corresponding to the directory wanted ...

I am a little bit lost : I don't know where to look to solve this issue ...

**Edit** : I don't know if it is important but I run the .exe on the same configuration on my computer and on other : from the USB Key (E:/).

Comment: Please don't post the error as an image. See [why not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Sorry for that, I changed it !

Comment: You are running java in that line. It seems that you don't have java installed on the other computer.

Comment: Installing java on the other computer solved my issue : thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing java on the other computer solved my issue.